# ScrollBy and scrollTo conflicting with browser scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, scrollto, scroll-snap, js-scrollby

I have created a simple carousel based on a native browser scrolling behaviour with the use of `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and `scroll-snap` technique. Works perfectly and is progressively enhanced. I trigger the carousel with js with `scrollBy` and `scrollTo` so it would act like a typical carousel. However when a user tries to navigate to a section on a page with `a href="#section-name` and the carousel runs, the user initiated vertical scroll stops before reaching its destination. Am I being dumb here and this a natural browser behaviour - you cannot have two scrolls at the same time? If so, how would you go about it? I want the carousel to run in a loop but if this brakes the navigation it does not make sense.
Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/rwaniek/pen/jOzNQpz

Comment: Just curious why you cannot have arrows to move between the slides and dots which acts as indicators and also clickable events for the respective slide?

Comment: I have used those in my real code, but that does not change anything if you want the carousel to run in the background. Typical use case - carousel with brand logos of some sponsors.